# one cache for all "objects" or one cache for each type? - web application with cache (guava)

Tags: java, gwt, guava

I am creating a web application that displays static data from back end. The data is of different types. to disburden the back end i have implemented a cache for one type with guava's cache.
now i need a cache for another type and the question is: implement a cache for this type or generalize the existing cache to handle "objects" (as far as i know i could give the different types different weights, right?).
the advantage of different caches is, that i could configure the separately - probably switching one cache off?!

but i am apprehending that on using separate caches i will loose some nasty google-engineered cache management stuff?!

what do you think about that?

Comment: You won't lose anything through multiple caches, as that is the norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead, use multiple caches.  There's no "nasty Google-engineered cache management stuff," as you'd see if you looked at the source code.

Comment: thx for this clear answer - reading it is easier than reading sources ;-)